# JavaScript - Join DataViews

Tags: javascript

How do I join [DataViews](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) in JavaScript?

Using WebUSB API to get data from a device:

```js
const a = await device1.transferIn(1, 64)).data;
const b = await device2.transferIn(1, 64)).data;

//const c = a + b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the `ArrayBuffer` which can be get from the `DataView`.

```
function appendBuffer(buffer1, buffer2) {
  var tmp = new Uint8Array(buffer1.byteLength + buffer2.byteLength);
  tmp.set(new Uint8Array(buffer1), 0);
  tmp.set(new Uint8Array(buffer2), buffer1.byteLength);
  return tmp.buffer;
};

const a = (await device1.transferIn(1, 64)).data.buffer;
const b = (await device2.transferIn(1, 64)).data.buffer;

const mergedArray = appendBuffer(a,b);
```